# filling an array in a struct c#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, assign

I'm trying to fill an array that is contained within a structure with some values but I keep getting errors no matter what I try.

my structure looks like this

```
public struct boardState
    {
        public int structid;
        public char[] state;
    }
```

bellow in the initializer I'm creating a new boardState and trying to fill it with some values like this

```
boardState _state_ = new boardState();
        _state_.structid = 1;
        _state_.state[9] = {'o','-','-','-','o','-','-','-','-','o'};
```

structid seems to work fine, but I get an error at the {'o','-' etc etc} telling me '; expected'. I've been through the code above and ensured that there are no ;'s missing (confirmed by the program running without this line) so I'm guessing you can't assign to the array in this way. How can I assign to the state array?

EDIT: - added the comma that I'd missed but still getting the same error.

Comment: Side note: please consider using class instead of struct. Or please confirm that you know what consequences of using struct in C# are (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: I just have to say that I agree with Alexei, and add that you have a mutable struct which is generally considered a bad idea. Also, by having an object in the structure, most of the purpose of the struct is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `[9]`. It tries to assign an array to a single char. Instead just use this:

```
_state_.state = new char [] {'o','-','-','-','o','-','-','-','-','o'};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma and the syntax is off.

**From:**

```
_state_.state[9] = {'o','-','-','-','o','-','-','-','-''o'};
```

**To:**

```
_state_.state = new char [] {'o','-','-','-','o','-','-','-','-','o'};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added that comma but I'm still getting the same error