# Prepare action for usage in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, properties, action

I want do define an action that sets a property with a value (calculated by a worker thread). That action should be called in another thread context (UI thread).

To simplify the problem - it boils down to the question: why does this code don't work and what do I have to do to make it work like intended:

```
    public struct Person
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    Person person;
    Action<Person> action;

    public void Update()
    {
        person = new Person();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            action = new Action<Person>(c => c.Name = "Me");
        }).Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        action(person);

        Debug.WriteLine(person.Name ?? "null");
    }
```

Why is this giving me "null" instead of "Sami"?

Comment: struct keyword is not present in java. This doesnot look like java.

Comment: This is most definitely C# (I tagged it).

Comment: Is this specifically how to set a UI component item from a background thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Person` is a struct. This means that when you pass `person` as an argument, a copy is made. So the action updates a copy, a not `person` itself. If you change `Person` to a class, you will see that your example works.

For more information about the difference between structs and classes, see [what's the difference between struct and class in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing link!

Answer (score 1):

To prove @ElianEbbing's answer:

```
   class Program {
      Person person;
      Action<Person> action;
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         Program p = new Program();
         p.Update();

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
      public void Update() {
         person = new Person();

         new Thread(() => {
            action = new Action<Person>(c => c.Name = "Sami");
         }).Start();

         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         action(person);

         Console.WriteLine(person.Name ?? "null");
      }
   }

   public class Person {
      public string Name;
   }
```

Because you declare Person as a struct, it is a value type - meaning a copy of Person is made. The Person object that has Name set to "Sami" is not the same Person object you are using to write the name.

Answer (score 1):

You are using threads and actions wrong.  By creating a thread that (sets an action to set the person's name), you are effectively doing nothing special.

```
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        action = new Action<Person>(c => c.Name = "Me");
    }).Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

is the same as

```
action = new Action<Person>(c => c.Name = "Me");
action(person);
```

What you wanted was something like this:

```
action = new Action<Person>(c => c.Name = "Me");
new Thread(action).Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but I didn't consider making corrections there. Although you do point out the correct use of action and Thread, it won't solve the OP's issue because `Person` is a struct. ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. You are absolutely correct. Thanks at all posters, u guys really helped me out!

Comment: Thought about this again - in the example I'm doing nothing special, but the thread is thought of as a worker thread. It may calculate something apart from the ui thread which i can use in the code within the action. I think I still need another thread to prepare the action.