# passing objects as parameters

Tags: c#

The application is printing 24 but shouldn't it be printing 18 when we know that without ref keyword only a copy of object is passed and no change is made to the original object.
I have created a class called myclass and an object me. age is a public variable in class myclass.
I have set me.age as 18 and through the method show I have changed it to 24.

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myclass me = new myclass();
        me.age = 18;
        show(me);
        Console.WriteLine(me.age);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void show( myclass you)
    {
        you.age = 24;        
    }
}

class myclass
{
    public int age;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "without ref keyword only a copy of object is passed and no change is made to the original object" is incorrect. A correct statement is "without the `ref` or `out` keyword a copy of the *value* is passed; no change is made to the original *variable* if the *value* came from a *variable*."  `ref` makes an alias to a *variable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse the variable and what the variable points to.

When you have:

```
MyClass myVar = new MyClass();
MyClass myVar2 = myVar;
```

That will create only a single instance of an object, but 2 variables pointing to it.

The same thing is happening to your parameter:  `you` is a copy of the variable `me`, but both point to the same object.  So when you modify `you.age`, you are also modifying `me.age`.

In your function, if you then did

```
you = new myClass();
```

only then would `me` and `you` refer to different objects.  If you did this, `me` would still point to the original object.

If you added `ref` to the parameter `you`, then if you did

```
you = new myClass();
```

then the variable `me` would be updated to point to that same object.

For objects, you need to separate the variable from what the variable points to.

Answer (score 2):

It's printing the right thing.

`myclass` is an object, and the default behavior is to pass the reference of the object in C#, so when you don't specify anything, you pass the reference.

If you declare `struct myclass` though, you'll have the behavior you want, because structs aren't references by default.

Comment: This is quite confusing. `struct`s inherit from `Object`, but they are not objects? And if this is just by default, does that mean you can pass an instance of a `class` by value?

Comment: In c# everything inherits from `Object`. But `struct` inherits first from `System.ValueType` (which then inherits from `Object` btw). The difference is made at the compiler level. When the compiler "sees" that something inherits from `System.ValueType` it passes the value, when it doesn't inherit from `System.ValueType` it passes the reference.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net there's a good explanation of the differences between a class and a struct

Answer (score 2):

You're probably confusing this with C++ classes. In C#, classes are *reference types*, which means that whenever you have a variable of a type that's class, that variable doesn't hold the object itself, it holds only a *reference* to it (you can think of it as a pointer). So, when you pass your object into a method, you actually pass a reference to that object. This means the behavior you're observing is correct.

C# also supports *value types* (unlike e.g. Java), which you create by using `struct` instead of `class`. If you changed `myclass` into a `srtuct`, you would get the behavior you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing value types and reference types.

```
public void addTwo(int a)
{
    a += 2;
}

...

int a = 5;
addTwo(a);
Console.WriteLine(a); // will give "5";
```

---

```
public void addTwo(ref int a)
{
    a += 2;
}

...

int a = 5;
addTwo(ref a);
Console.WriteLine(a); // will give "7";
```

For reference types (anything that is defined as `class` instead of `struct`, what you are passing on is a reference to the object, not a copy. So you are in fact changing the object.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an **object** to your function.

Not an atomic type or a struct, therefor it is sent by reference (this is how C# works), anything you change in this object in the function will also change in the original object because it is the same.

More information about passing parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx