# Why can't we use single ListItem Object to add the items in a DropDownList ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

On using the same ListItem Object to the DropDownList in ASP.net (C#), it displays the last item Text & Value. The Code is written below,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    ListItem itm = new ListItem();  
    itm.Text = "AAA";  
    itm.Value = "AAA";  
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(itm);  

    itm.Text = "BBB";  
    itm.Value = "BBB";  
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(itm);  

    itm.Text = "CCC";  
    itm.Value = "CCC";  
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(itm);  

    itm.Text = "DDD";  
    itm.Value = "DDD";  
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(itm);  
}
```

The DropDownList shows 4 items but all have the text as "DDD". But if I add

**itm = new listItem();**

before assigning the new Text & value, it displays the as desired. AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD.

What is the reason?

Comment: Look up reference type vs value type.  You need to do the `new ListItem()` declaration to ensure you are working with a new reference and not the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListItem is an object and there is only one instance of it in memory. The variable itm only holds the address to the object in memory. When you add the listitem to the dropdown list, the dropdown copies the address in the variable internally. So you are adding the same object 4 times to the dropdownlist. When the dropdown is later rendered and it checks the Text and Value properties, they are set with the last values you set in the above code which is "DDD".

Using New will instantiate a new object in memory, and the address in your variable will point to the new object.

Look up the topic on reference vs value types which should help you to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding one instance to a collection which is displayed. When you change the value of itm.Text you change the value in memory for that one item inside of the collection. When you add itm = new listItem() you are creating a new instance in memory that will have a new value. Basically you are creating a new address in memory.

Comment: I understand that by using itm = new listItem(), I am allocating another memory to the object itm. But then it should not point to the previous one. But once I had added the itm Object to the DropDownList & then changed the value of itm (without using itm = new ListItem()), another value can be assigned to the same object to be added as a second item in the ddl.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer you should have a look at the difference between value and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance of a class using itm = new listItem() makes itm a reference in memory to the class.  In other words it holds the address of the listItem object.  Every time you change the values of it's attributes, the same object is being updated in memory.  So when you add the object to your dropdown list, you are also only adding the reference.  Therefore every time the object gets updated, each instance of the reference will also get updated.  If you want to assign the values only you can use a struct instead of a class.  Structs are value types and classes are reference types.

see this for more details on the difference between structs and classes

[What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)