# Vector of an object instant VB Net

Tags: c++, vb.net

I have problem with vector in VB NET.

I have written a code in C++

```
typedef struct
{
    int process;
    int burstTime;
    int ArrivalTime;
    int remaining;
    int timeAddedToQ;
    bool flag;
} process;

vector<process> proc;
```

How can I represent this C++ code in VB NET code?

I tried searching Google but nothing helped. Will really apreciate if anyone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically make a class for the `Process` information, then use `List(Of Process)` to replace the `vector<process>`.

```
Public Class Process
    Property Process As Integer
    Property BurstTime As Integer
    Property ArrivalTime As Integer
    Property Remaining As Integer
    Property Flag as Boolean
End Class

' Use in code as:
Dim proc as New List(Of Process)
```

Answer (score 2):

Structures in VB are declared as follows:

```
Public Structure process
    Public process As Integer 
    Public burstTime As Integer
    Public ArrivalTime As Integer
    Public remaining As Integer
    Public timeAddedToQ As Integer
    Public flag As Boolean
End Structure
```

However you should be certain [you want a structure and not a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net).
`vector` does not have a *direct* translation to VB, but `List<T>` is probably the closest:

```
Dim proc As New List(Of process)
```

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for the link. I'm not a VB guy, i dont really know about VB stuff.