# Is datetime struct or class in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I just started c#. But can not figure out `DateTime`. I know it is a struct but why do I see different ways of initialize it like class sometime.

How is this if it is a struct?

```
DateTime myValue = DateTime.Now;  // This is struct

DateTime myValue2 = new DateTime(); // This is class with +11 overloads.
```

So is there two versions of datetime in c# one is struct and other is class?

Comment: Structs can have constructors, and DateTime is only a struct

Comment: See [**struct**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx). Read the remarks section.

Comment: Also, see [What's the difference between a struct and class in .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: Voting to close because the question is clearly answered by the documentation on MSDN.

Comment: Additionally, `DateTime.Now` is just a property which returns an instance of DateTime with the current time value. Even reference types can do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A type cannot be a `struct` and a by-reference type at the same time. Both constructs make a `DateTime`, which is a value type (also known as the `struct`).

The difference between the two is that the first produces the value to be copied inside a static property called `Now`, and the second initializes the value through one of `DateTime`'s 11 constructors.

Answer (score 9):

The use of the keyword `new` does not mean that it is creating an instance of a class.  It is creating an instance of a struct.  Structs can have constructors too, and they are initialized (in C#) using the same syntax as classes, despite being structs.

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a struct. And structs might have constructors too.Take a look at this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) If you want to be surprised, you can define an integer like this:

```
int x = new int();
```

Comment: Technically, they are guaranteed to have their default parameterless constructor.

Comment: The link [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) says `Structs fall into these categories` etc. Why the categories don't include DateTime?

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a structure. To know which type is something, you can do two things :

1) Look at [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for DateTime it is clearly indicated in the title
2) Hover over the type. Visual Studio will pop a tooltip : [image]

Structs behave *mostly* like classes, you can instantiate them with the `new` operator and they can have methods too. You cannot use the way they are instantiated as a way to tell if something is struct or a class.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the tooltip. Hitting F12 on the keyword while `DateTime` is selected also takes you to the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a `struct`.

Which doesn't mean it can't have many different constructors and methods and overloads.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is a struct: [MSDN Struct Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29).aspx. Structs can have constructor overloads.

By the way, if you hover over `DateTime` with your cursor, Intellisense says *`struct System.DateTime`*.

Answer (score -3):

A Struct is more like a lightweight class, and a value instead of an object. A DateTime is one of those struct