# Adding elements to a list of class

Tags: c#, list, class

I have defined motorData class as below:

```
public class motorData
 {
     public int data0 { get; set; }
     public int data1 { get; set; }
     public int data2 { get; set; }
     public int data3 { get; set; } 
     public int data4 { get; set; }
     public int data5 { get; set; }
     public int data6 { get; set; }
     public int data7 { get; set; }
     public int data8 { get; set; }
 }
```

The class is used in a `Button` click event like this:

```
List<motorData> mtdlist = new List<motorData>();
motorData mtd = new motorData();

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    mtd.data0 = 1;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd);
    mtd.data0 = 2;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd);
    mtd.data0 = 3;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd);
    mtd.data0 = 4;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd);
    mtd.data0 = 5;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd);

}
```

After calling the event, I get the following results:

```
mtdlist[0].data0 = 5;  
mtdlist[1].data0 = 5;  
mtdlist[2].data0 = 5; 
mtdlist[3].data0 = 5;  
mtdlist[4].data0 = 5;
```

If I define motorData as structure, I get the correct results. So what am I missing?

Comment: How do you want the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between struct and class in .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value to the same Object ,You should create new Object each time.

```
List<motorData> mtdlist = new List<motorData>();

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    motorData mtd1 = new motorData();
    mtd1.data0 = 1;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd1);
    motorData mtd2 = new motorData();
    mtd2.data0 = 2;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd2);
    motorData mtd3 = new motorData();
    mtd3.data0 = 3;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd3);
    motorData mtd4 = new motorData();
    mtd4.data0 = 4;
    motorData mt5 = new motorData();
    mtdlist.Add(mtd4);
    mtd5.data0 = 5;
    mtdlist.Add(mtd5);

}
```

To know more about [`Structure vs Class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: Could you maybe expand on this a bit?

Comment: @Rawling Expand what?

Comment: Pretty much what you put in the link :D