# C# 2 variables pointing to the same object

Tags: c#, reference, unity-game-engine

In my project I have a very simple assignment.

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(0,0,0);
Vector3 v2 = v1;
v2.x = 10;
Debug.Log(v1);
```

The above code prints `"0,0,0"`. If this was Java it would print `"10,0,0"` because `v2` would reference `v1`. How do I get this in C#?

I want v1 and v2 to point to the same object. This is also part of a unity project but I don't think that's relevant here?

Comment: [Difference between struct and class in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net) will explain it better than I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity3d, `Vector3` is not a reference type (class). It's a value type (struct). Which means it behaves *in this sense* more like a primitive would in Java.

When you assign, you're copying, not referencing the same object.

What you *can* do is call a method using the `ref` keyword, and allow *that* to modify an existing `Vector3`:

```
private static void Vector3Test()
{
    Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    ChangeVector(ref v1);

    Debug.Log(v1);
}

private static void ChangeVector(ref Vector3 vector)
{
    vector.x = 10;
}
```

This will output `"10,0,0"` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is because **Vector3** is **`Structure`** type not **`Class`** type. It's a value type, not a reference type, like Class. So when you assign it, it will copy a new value, but their address in memory is not same.