# Two array's element reference to an object

Tags: c#, reference

I have the following code:

```
struct NewType
{
    public int val;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NewType i = new NewType();
    List<NewType> IList = new List<NewType>();

    i.val = 1;
    IList.Add(i);

    i.val = 2;
    IList.Add(i);
}
```

After that, If I print each of element in IList list, the result will be **12**
It's opposite than what I thought **22**

Because:
[image]

Someone tells me why the result was **12**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `NewType` is a `struct`, which is added to the list as a value type (a copy of the object is added to the list, not the reference to the original object).

If you changed it from `struct` to `class` then it would be as you expected. The class is passed by reference.

Have a look at [Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)

> A struct is a value type. When a struct is created, the variable to
>   which the struct is assigned holds the struct's actual data. When the
>   struct is assigned to a new variable, it is copied. The new variable
>   and the original variable therefore contain two separate copies of the
>   same data. Changes made to one copy do not affect the other copy.

Answer (score 2):

The type `NewType` is a value type, not a reference type. That means that `IList`, whose type is `List<NewType>`, holds copies of the values not references to them. That being said, your picture is not correct.

> After that, If I print each of element in IList list, the result will
>   be 12 It's opposite than what I thought 22

This is the expected.

Here

```
i.val = 1;
IList.Add(i);
```

You add a copy of the value of i in the `IList`. This copy's the value of val is 1.

Then

```
i.val = 2;
IList.Add(i);
```

You change the value of the `val` by copying to it the value of 2. After this you add a copy of `i` to the `IList`. This copy's value of val is 2.

In order you notice that you have described in your question, the type `NewType` should be a reference type. If you change the definition of `NewType` to the following one:

```
class NewType
{
    public int val;
}
```

you will notice thta you have described.

Answer (score 1):

Because `NewType` is a `struct` and *struct is a value type but not reference type like class*. If you have `class` instead of struct you will get `22`, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net) will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Basic data types work different than abstract data types. ints are not references and therefore are actually copied unlike non-basic data types.

Answer (score 0):

`IList.Add(i)` performs implicitely a shallow copy of `i` because `NewType` is a value type (a struct). While performing the shallow copy, it copies also the field `NewType.val` by value. So `IList` contains two different `NewType` values, which themselves contain a different `val` integer.

If you change `NewType` from `struct` to `class`, then you will get what you are expecting.