# How to add into structure arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having troubles in adding into an array.
I have created a class named Products:

```
public struct newProducts
{
    public string productBrand;
    public string productType;
    public string productName;
    public string productFlavour;
    public int productSize;
}

//Create an array of type newProducts
newProducts[] productList = new productList[];
```

and than I've created a function:

```
public newProducts AddProduct(string brand, string type, string name, string flavour, int size)
{
    //I don't know what to do here..

    return productList;
}
```

What I want to do is to append and store the brand, type, name, flavour and size values to the array

Basically the first time I call this function I'll enter those values and store it to index 0 and on the second call it will add them to index 1 .

Is this possible?

Comment: Unless you are a pro, and you really know what you are doing, don't use `struct` in C#. Use `class`.

Comment: Your class appears to be a struct. Structs and classes are very different constructs.

Comment: Also you're trying to create an array of `productList`'s which is the variable name, not the type name.

Comment: I recommend just using `List` and `.Add()`

Comment: Arrays in .NET are "fixed" size. You don't add elements to them. Use `List<newProducts>` for doing it.

Comment: Also, can't really add to arrays. Use List<T>.

Comment: Pretty easy, really. Though if you use `List<newProducts>` it's easier. Also, word of advice, use Pascal-Casing for type-names. (`NewProducts`) And don't use `struct`s with `string`s. Generally a `struct` object should be small. (Less than 16 bytes by Microsoft's recommendation.)

Answer (score 5):

You're better off using a `List<T>` instead of a `T[]`. That way, you can append values any time, without having to worry about resizing the array yourself

```
List<NewProduct> products = new List<NewProduct>();
products.Add(new Product { /* more code here */ });
```

Also, you might be coming from a lower level programming background, but as others mentioned, I'm not sure you really understand the true meaning of `struct` in C#. By looking at your code, you're looking for a `class`:

```
public class NewProduct
{
    public string ProductBrand { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductFlavour { get; set; }
    public int ProductSize { get; set; }
}
```

I'd suggest starting by reading [Classes and Structs (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) and [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: dont read that article - you dont need a struct you need a class

Comment: @pm100 Why shouldn't he read *that* (not sure which one you're referring to) article?

Comment: OP is clearly a beginner - he does not need to use a struct. Maybe I should have said 'read that article - but you dont need a struct'

Comment: @pm100 I know, I've stated that in the answer to be obvious :) No harm in doing some reading.

Comment: I get the point thanks =) I'll go with a class, not sure if what I need to use is a list..

Comment: @user3456351 Why do you think a list doesn't fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue, thank you for pointing out the differences between structures and classes, here's my approach:

I've changed the elements as Yuval described.. get and set methods..

than created a list of type newProduct class in the main form class

later on inside the main form class I created a method to insert data to the class elements and added it to the list! and it worked fine

thanks everyone in advance and sorry for my bad english