# Member pass-through in C#?

Tags: c#, syntactic-sugar

Go has a [nice feature](https://github.com/a8m/go-lang-cheat-sheet#embedding) where members of a nested struct are automatically accessible via its parent struct:

```
// Server exposes all the methods that Logger has
type Server struct {
    Host string
    Port int
    *log.Logger
}

// initialize the embedded type the usual way
server := &Server{"localhost", 80, log.New(...)}

// methods implemented on the embedded struct are passed through
server.Log(...) // calls server.Logger.Log(...)

// the field name of the embedded type is its type name (in this case Logger)
var logger *log.Logger = server.Logger
```

Is the same possible in C#, for example using `implicit` casts?

```
struct B
{
    public int x;
}

struct A
{
    public B b;
}

var a = new A();

a.b.x = 1; // How it usually works
a.x = 1; // How Go works, assuming x is unambiguous
```

Comment: No, there's nothing like that in C#. You could always add your own property that delegates though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept in C#. You can add such properties by yourself, but it will be very confusing for other developers who see your code.

```
struct B
{
    public int x;
}

struct A
{
    public B b;
    public int x {
        get { return b.x; }
        set { b.x = value; }
    }
}

}

var a = new A();

a.b.x = 1;
a.x = 1;
```

---

However if you switch to classes instead of structs - you can have similar behavior using [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx):

```
class B
{
    public int x;
}

class A : B
{
}

var a = new A();
a.x = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

An embedded Golang struct can be seen as a sort of "inheritance". If you want simulate this behaviour in C# you should use a class instead of struct ([here if you want know the difference between struct and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)).
Something like this:

```
public class A {
    public int X {get; set;}
}
public class B : A{
    B : base() {}
}
...
var a = new B();
a.X = 24;
```

Comment: That is true, but I would rather use a compositional style in C#. Mixins, for example, are much nicer with this syntactic-sugar.