# Cannot register a struct instance with autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I just started moving to *Autofac* from *Unity* and I have a problem when trying to register an instance.

```
public static void Register(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder,
                            CancellationToken shutDownCancellationToken)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<CancellationToken>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(shutDownCancellationToken);
}
```

I get the following error:

> The type '`CancellationToken`' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter '`T`' in the generic type or method '`RegistrationExtensions.RegisterInstance<T>(ContainerBuilder, T)`'

Anyone knows how to register an already created struct instance?

Comment: How 'CancellationToken' is defined?

Comment: CancellationTokenSource shutDownCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Comment: Please provide Definition! not instance creation.

Comment: what do you mean definition?

Comment: Class definition of 'CancellationToken'. Also what is association between `CancellationTokenSource`  and `CancellationToken`

Comment: A `CancellationToken` is used to cancel a task but `Autofac` is used to manage the instance of all task. Why would you need to register a `cancellationToken` ?

Comment: @Amit I was saying about Threading CancellationToken. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx shutDownCancellationTokenSource  is created using a CancellationTokenSource at my microservice root which is used to Cancel() when OnStop fires

Comment: @Cyril Durand I have several services running and when I shut down the Microservice I need a global cancellation token (shutdown) that kills all background tasks running in my services.

Comment: The real question is here: why do you want to inject a struct? A struct is _runtime data_, and this is not something you should inject, as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `RegisterInstance` method as a `class` constraint that disallow `struct` registration but `CancellationToken` is a `struct` this is why you have this error message. To bypass this constraint, you can register your instance using the `Register` method.

```
builder.Register(_ => source.Token).As<CancellationToken>();
```

As long as your struct is immutable, you will have the expected behavior, but if you use a mutable struct, the instance won't be share. In your case, `CancellationToken` is immutable you won't have any weird side effect.

---

**But why has `RegisterInstance` a `class` constraint ?**

When you register an instance using the `RegisterInstance` method, the expected behavior is to share the same instance each time the object is injected.

By definition a `struct` acts like a copy and not like a reference. See [Struct vs Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net) for more information.

Imagine you have the following struct and service using this struct :

```
public struct Foo
{
    public Int32 A { get; set; }
}
public class Service
{
    public Service(Foo foo)
    {
        this._foo = foo;
    }

    private Foo _foo;

    public void Set(Int32 a)
    {
        this._foo.A = a;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this._foo.A);
    }
}
```

and the following code using these service :

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

Foo f = new Foo();
builder.Register(_ => f).As<Foo>();
builder.RegisterType<Service>();
IContainer container = builder.Build();

Service service1 = container.Resolve<Service>();
Service service2 = container.Resolve<Service>();

service1.Set(3);
service1.Print();
service2.Print();
```

Even if you register only *one* instance of `Foo` it will display 3 and 0. I think this is the reason why `RegisterInstance` has a `class` constraint.