# Use of struct with for loop

Tags: c#, struct

I want to translate following c++ code into c#. But I do not know how to loop through "FILM" (like film [n] in c++), instead of each one calling separately.

Can someone also make the suggestion for better translation of this code?

C++ Code

```
// array of structures
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct movies_t {
  string title;
  int year;
} films [3];

void printmovie (movies_t movie);

int main ()
{
  string mystr;
  int n;

  for (n=0; n<3; n++)
  {
    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,films[n].title);
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
  }

  cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
  for (n=0; n<3; n++)
    printmovie (films[n]);
  return 0;
}

void printmovie (movies_t movie)
{
  cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
}
```

My c# attemp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MAKEGROUP {
    class Program {
        struct movies_t {
            public string title;
            public int year;

            public  void printmovie(movies_t movie) {
                Console.Write(movie.title);
                Console.Write(" (");
                Console.Write(movie.year);
                Console.Write(")\n");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            movies_t FILM = new movies_t();
            movies_t FILM1 = new movies_t();
            FILM1.title = "Hero";
            FILM1.year = 1990;

            movies_t FILM2 = new movies_t();
            FILM2.title = "Titanic";
            FILM2.year = 1997;

            movies_t FILM3 = new movies_t();
            FILM3.title = "Mission impossible";
            FILM3.year = 1996;

            // How can I use for loop 
            // for the following code

            FILM.printmovie(FILM1);
            FILM.printmovie(FILM2);
            FILM.printmovie(FILM3);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't try to port the C++ directly to C#. They have different idioms. Mutable structs in C# are almost always a bad idea. An idiomatic port of the *aims* of the C++ code would look very little like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the working code, tested with linqpad (explanation follows):

```
void Main()
{
    var films = new List<Movie> {
        new Movie("Hero",1990 ),
        new Movie("Titanic",1997 ),
        new Movie("Mission impossible",1996 ),
    };

    foreach(var film in films)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(film.GetCompleteTitle());
    }
}


class Movie
{
    public String Title { get; }
    public Int32 Year { get; }

    public Movie(String title, Int32 year) => (Title, Year) = (title, year);

    public String GetCompleteTitle() => $"{Title} ({Year})";
}
```

Explanation:

1. **Array are not necessary** if the size can change and you want to make the initialization more readable
2. You should use a **class**, you don't need a value type to handle the movie concept
3. Use the **constructor** to give only one way to initialize the variable
4. Try avoid coupling your class with the console by **moving the print outside** the method
5. Hide the fields and make it read only with the [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) to hide the field implementation detail
6. You can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to compose the string in a readable way
7. [Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) can be used to return methods or assign with less code
8. [Tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-a-tuple) can be used to assign both the constructor parameters to the properties and keep the code more compact

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you should do:

- **Replace `struct` with a `class`** - unlike C++, C# makes a deeper distinction between `struct`s and classes. In this case a `class` is more appropriate
- **Give your `class` a constructor** - this would help you protect `year` and `title` properties from being changed after construction
- **Make an array of your classes** - do this instead of creating `FILM1`, `FILM2`, and `FILM3`.
- **Optionally, give your class a `ToString()` methid** - this would let you print instances of your class easier.

The class would look like this:

```
class Film {
    string Title {get;}
    int Year {get;}
    public Film(string title, int year) {
        Title = title;
        Year = year;
    }
}
```

Array initialization would look like this:

```
Film[] film = new Film[] {
    new Film("Hero", 1990)
,   new Film("Titanic", 1997)
,   new Film("L'Arroseur Arrosé", 1895)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would minimally rewrite that:

```
var films = new List<movies_t>();

var hero = new movies_t { 
    title = "Hero",
    year = 1990
};

films.Add(hero);

//  Similar syntax for the same thing:
fiilms.Add(new movies_t { title = "Titanic", year = 1997 });
```

But you should be making other changes too.

Don't make `movies_t` a struct. Make it a class. `struct` means something different in those two languages. And please use C# naming conventions.

In C#, your code should look more like this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie() 
    {
    }

    public Movie(string title, int year) 
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Year = year;
    }

    public string Title;
    public int Year;

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return $"{Title} ({Year})";
    }
}

//  ...snip...

var films = new List<Movie>();

var hero = new Movie("Hero", 1990);

films.Add(hero);

//  Similar syntax for the same thing:
films.Add(new Movie("Titanic", 1997));

foreach (var film in films)
{
    //  This will call Movie.ToString() to "convert" film to a string. 
    Console.WriteLine(film);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Movie[] movies = new Movie[]
    {
        new Movie("Hero", 1990),
        new Movie("Titanic", 1997),
        new Movie("Mission Impossible", 1996),
    };

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < movies.Length; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(movies[i].ToString());
}
```

Also, use `class` instead of `struct`, since it's more appropriate (for more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)). Here is what I suggest you (conforming to the worked example above):

```
public class Movie
{
    public String Title { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Year { get; private set; }

    public Movie(String title, Int32 year)
    {
        Title = title;
        Year = year;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return (title + " (" + year.ToString() + ")");
    }
}
```