# Create object with new and without new

Tags: c#

I started to learn C# and I found out that there are two different ways to create the object.
First is this:

```
 Box Box1 = new Box();   // Declare Box1 of type Box
 Box Box2 = new Box();   // Declare Box2 of type Box
```

Other is this:

```
 Box Box1 ;   // Declare Box1 of type Box
 Box Box2 ;   // Declare Box2 of type Box
```

Both methods work, what is the difference?
Is there something similar with C++ pointer?

```
Box* Box1 = new Box();   // Declare Box1 of type Box
Box* Box2 = new Box();   // Declare Box2 of type Box
```

Comment: Your second snippet declares two variables, but doesn't create any objects.

Comment: `Box Box1` does not instantiate an object.

Comment: Box is a class, then the Box1 and Box2 are the objects in the second method right?
what is mean by the instantiate an object?

Comment: `Box Box1; Console.WriteLine(Box1);` will give you "use of unassigned local variable", demonstrating that the statement declares but does not instantiate. (When used as a field, `Box Box1`would be considered initialized, but with `null`, not an object.)

Comment: Is `Box` a `class` or a `struct` ?  Makes all the difference in C#.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: you can't use `struct` variables without initializing them either (with the very limited exception of a `struct` that has no members).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - the OP isn't using them yet. I can't tell from the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example declares a variable, but it will be empty and can't be accessed:

```
Box b;
int id = b.Id; // Compiler will tell you that you're trying to use a unassigned local variable
```

We can fool the compiler by initializing with null:

```
Box b = null; // initialize variable with null
try
{
    int id = b.Id; // Compiler won't notice that this is empty. An exception will be trown
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

We see now, that we have to initialize the variable in order to access it:

```
Box b; // declare an empty variable
b = new Box(); // initialize the variable

int id = b.Id; // now we're allowed to use it.
```

Short version of declare and initialize is your 1st example:

```
Box b = new Box();
```

Here the example-class i used for the examples:

```
public class Box
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Perhaps you did notice that `Id` in our `Box` is not being initialized. This is not needed (but most times you should do) because it is a value-type ([`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct)) and not a refenrence-type ([`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class)).

If you want to read more, have a look at this Question: [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: You assume Box is a class. What if it is a Value Type instead?

Comment: Correct. Added an explaination for not initializing Id because it is a `struct`. I'll have a look for the Link to the MS Docs..

Comment: "Compiler will tell you that this is illegal, because "b" is "null"." - no, the compiler will tell you that this is illegal because the variable isn't *definitely assigned*. That's very different from it being defined with a null value.