# how i can declare a array of structure in a structure in VB?

Tags: vb.net, structure

I have a structure A that contain 2 integer, 1 String, and 1 array of another Struct B.

In a function, i want to initialize the size of the array of structure B, but Microsoft Visual Basic don't want to accept all try I do.

the struct A

```
    Structure XpGrpData
        Dim Mode As Integer
        Dim XpValue As Integer
        Dim Name As String
        Dim player As XpUsrData()
    End Structure
```

the struct B

```
    Structure XpUsrData
        Dim Mode As Integer
        Dim XpValue As Integer
        Dim Name As String
    End Structure
```

how i do normally the thing

```
Dim CurrentXpData As XpGrpData
CurrentXpData.player = New XpGrpData(myValue)
```

But my IDE says "Too Much Arguments for 'Public Sub New()'".
How I can set the size of my array ?

Comment: You need to add a constructor `Sub New()` that takes an argument for every field in that struct. Also.... ideally a struct is *immutable* - consider making it a `Class` if you're treating it as any old object.

Comment: I agree with Mr. Guindon. Also use `List(Of YourClass)` instead of an array, It's much better and you can access through your items more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it right now, to instantiate the structure I would use:

```
Dim CurrentXpData as XpGrpData = New XpGrpData()
```

When passing an argument into the constructor it is expecting you to have defined what you want to do with argument. For example in a struct / class you would add a New() subroutine:

```
public sub New(myInput)
    me.someProperty = myInput
end sub
```

As already mentioned you may want to consider a Class unless you specifically need a Struct. [They handle memory differently and a class is usually advantageous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern worked for me to work around the awkward syntax error:

```
Dim temp(myValue) As XpGrpData
CurrentXpData.player = temp
```