# Modify class field in for-loop without creating a new instance

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I don't understand how to achive something like this (as I would do in a language like C++):

```
List<Element> _elements = ... // Created before
for (var i = 0; i < _elements.Count; i++)
{
    _elements[i].Color = Color.Black;
}
```

It gives me: `Indexer access returns temporary value. Cannot modify struct member when accessed struct is not classified as a variable`, which I find weird because I have specified the field with `{ get; set; }`, shouldn't the example above "use" the setter?

I only get it to work by creating a new instance and copying the other values of my class `Element` (which contains `Color` and `Value`), which is weird, because the error message above said indexer returns a **temporary** value that I would then just overwrite.
It also feels wrong, and would be tedious for any larger data types:

```
List<Element> _elements = ... // Created before
for (var i = 0; i < _elements.Count; i++)
{
    _elements[i] = new Element(_elements[i].Value, Color.Black);
}
```

Is the problem that I am using List? Or should I iterate in some other way?

Element class is super simple:

```
public struct Element
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Element(long value, Color color)
    {
        Value = value;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This was edited to better show that this question is not about assignment, but that `_elements` is already created.

Comment: In the title you say "class" field, but it's not a class (reference type), it's a struct (value type). That's basically the big difference.

Comment: You'd have to make a local copy, mutate that and then assign it back like  `var temp = _elements[i]; temp.Color = Color.Black; _element[i] = temp;` however mutable structs are evil as you run into issues like this.

Comment: Should `Element` be a `struct` in the first place? Have you read the differences between classes and struct in c#?

Comment: `which I find weird because I have specified the field with { get; set; }, shouldn't the example above "use" the setter?` a) That is a property, not a field. b) It isn't complaining about the `.Color` it is complaining about the `_elements[i].Color` _as a whole_. The compiler is rightfully pointing out "hey this thing you are doing makes no sense whatsoever, so I won't let you do it".

Comment: `struct` is a valuetype. When you access this struct using indexer, it creates a temporary value and assigns it to that value. Due to it being valuetype, this assignment causes a copy of the value. So now you have a copy of a value, completely independent of the struct that's inside your List, you modify it and nothing will happen.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Basically making Element a class solves the problem. 

My big mistake here was litte bit overlooking the big difference between structs and classes in C# versus C++ (which I wrote a bit before starting C#).  Thus making this question seem rather poorly researched before asking it. 

I appriciate your time and clarification. Thanks a lot.
And I will take a deeper dive into the difference right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `struct` (value type), not a `class` (reference type).

So, when you write `_elements[i]`, you don't have a reference to the same object that is in the list, you have a whole *copy* of the Element.

This difference between class/struct is also noticeable when you pass parameters of functions.

Here are some possibilities:

## Option 1:

Use a class instead of a struct.

## Option 2a:

You can reassign the "slot" in the list, `_elements[i] = new Element(....)` you already noticed that.

> It also feels wrong, and would be tedious for any larger data types:

A bit, see 2b.

## Option 2b:

Just use a temporary variable and reassign the value,

```
var temp = _elements[i];
temp.Color= Color.Black;
_elements[i] = temp;
```

no need to recreate another new Element value here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "modify *class* field" in your for-loop, then create a `class` not a `struct` -

```cs
public class Element    // this one is a class, not a struct
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Element(long value, Color color)
    {
        Value = value;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

As for the distinction, take a look at this post - [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: While this correctly answers my question, I've made an edit to it that ``_elements`` was created before and not right before the for-loop, thus clarifying that the question was not about assignment.
Thanks for answer and the link, definitely need to read up on that :)

Comment: @viesa, Ok, I'll remove the suggestion then  :)

Answer (score -2):

I was working this out and in the process of posting when a couple of comments came in that said basically the same things.  This may help to understand better what comments are stating.

```
List<Element> _elements = new List<Element>(5);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Element E =new Element();
    E.Color = Colors.MediumAquamarine;

    _elements.Add(E);
}
```