# Sprite not moving in unity 2D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm following a tutorial on making a game but when I wrote what they wrote it wouldn't move.

The script is attached to sprite but when I hit <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> it doesn't move.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movment : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public float speed = 5f;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
           float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
           float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

           Vector2 pos = transform.position;

           pos.x += h * speed * Time.deltaTime;
           pos.y += v * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Vector2` is a value type (a struct), `Vector2 pos = transform.position` will make a copy of the transform position and the original position remains unaffected by any changes you make to `pos`. To update the position, use `transform.position = pos` once `pos` is set to the new position:

```cs
void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector2 pos = transform.position;

    pos.x += h * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    pos.y += v * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

See: [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: So what do I have to do?

Comment: @BraydenTodorov You need to apply pos back on the sprite position.

Comment: @BraydenTodorov Don't forget to accept the answer if this solution worked for you!