# C# Extension method change current value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, extension-methods

Is there a way to change the Unity Vector3 struct value inside an Extension Method in this way?

```
Vector3 myVector = new Vector(3.5f, 0.7f, 2f);
myVector.Floor(); // it should be (3f, 0f, 2f) instead it's (3.5f, 0.7f, 2f) still
```

it only works in this way:

```
myVector = myVector.Floor(); // now it's (3f, 0f, 2f)
```

Extension Code:

```
public static void Floor(this Vector3 vector)
{
    vector.Set(Mathf.Floor(vector.x), Mathf.Floor(vector.y), Mathf.Floor(vector.z));
}
```

or

```
public static void Floor(this Vector3 vector)
{
    vector.x = Mathf.Floor(vector.x);
    vector.y = Mathf.Floor(vector.y);
    vector.z = Mathf.Floor(vector.z);
}
```

Comment: Vector3 seems to be a struct have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your extension method should be like this:

```
public static void Floor(ref this Vector3 vector)
{
    vector.x = Mathf.Floor(vector.x);
    vector.y = Mathf.Floor(vector.y);
    vector.z = Mathf.Floor(vector.z);
}
```

because struct is value type

Here's an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NItg0O

Comment: can a static extension actually have the ref keyword?

Comment: yes i reproduced it in my end and works properly

Comment: Are you sure that's possible? Did you try this?

Comment: Which C# version?

Comment: The version i used is c# 10.0

Comment: This works in C# 9.0 yet

Comment: I hate mutable structs and so should you. Doing `Floor(this Vector3 vector) => new Vector3(Math.Floor(vector.x), ...` would the way to go to avoid the pitfalls of mutability with structs.