# Customized C# Chained Calls Not Functioning as Expected

Tags: c#, chained

I've customized a C# class for chaining calls to add my styles, but when I first create an instance of the style class and then use chaining calls, it only displays the first added style in the end.

Here is the code:

MyStyleBuilder:

```
namespace TestStyleBuilder
{
    public struct MyStyleBuilder
    {

        private string stringBuffer;

        public MyStyleBuilder AddLineColor(string value) => this.AddStyle("color", value);

        public MyStyleBuilder AddLineDash(string value) => this.AddStyle("dash", value);

        public MyStyleBuilder AddStyle(string prop, string value)
        {
            var style = $"{prop}:{value};";
            stringBuffer += style;
            return this;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return stringBuffer != null ? stringBuffer.Trim() : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
using TestStyleBuilder;

// Output:
// color:color;dash:dash;
MyStyleBuilder builder1 = new MyStyleBuilder().AddLineColor("color").AddLineDash("dash");
Console.WriteLine(builder1.ToString());

// Output:
// color:color;
MyStyleBuilder builder2 = new MyStyleBuilder();
builder2.AddLineColor("color").AddLineDash("dash");
Console.WriteLine(builder2.ToString());
```

After debugging and tracing, I found that all the styles were added in the MyStyleBuilder, but when returning to the test class, only one style was added.

My guess is that in the second example, the returned this is not equivalent to builder2, which is causing this behavior.

However, I'm not sure how to modify it to achieve the desired effect of continuous style addition in the second approach.

Comment: How about using a class instead? Is that an option?

Comment: `struct MyStyleBuilder` has value semantics. Returning this, creates a copy of the struct, leaving the old `builder2.stringBuffer` unchanged.

Comment: as we don't know your test-code where it fails, we can only *guess* about your problem, which is that `struct`-instances are *copied* instead of *referenced* when passing them to or from methods.

Comment: `builder2 = builder2.AddLineColor("color").AddLineDash("dash");` - this will work in the case of a structure.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov sure, however we have no idea what OP is doing with that builder afterwards, making this question pretty unclear.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I tried this method, and it worked.

Comment: Ignoring the bug for a moment: this is a *terrible* way to build strings - this is super allocatey

Comment: @MarcGravell Emmm, forgive me, I don't understand why this approach is very space-consuming.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think I understand. A copy of the struct will be created every time I call the style method. Thanks!

Comment: @personax I wasn't talking about the struct - the struct will be on the stack here: it isn't an allocation (at least in the GC sense); rather - I'm talking about the many strings. Every concatenation creates an additional strong the length of the old string plus the new bit - essentially creating a telescopic allocation.

Comment: `stringBuffer += style` is equivalent to `stringBuffer = stringBuffer + style` which must allocate a new buffer, copy both string segments into it, assign the new pointer. As `stringBuffer` grows, the copy step will take longer and longer. Eventually the garbage collector will notice that the old `stringBuffer` is unused and release the memory. Copying the `struct` is almost free, since all your variables are on the stack. In an optimised release build the struct might at well not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `return this` from a struct method, a copy of `this` is returned, because structs have value semantics.

`builder2.AddLineColor("color")` is modifying `builder2.stringBuffer`, but `AddLineDash("dash")` is modifying the `stringBuffer` of the copy returned by `builder2.AddLineColor("color")`. That's why when you inspect `builder2.stringBuffer`, only the color is applied. The copy returned by `AddLineDash("dash")` has both styles applied, but you discarded that by not assigning to anything.

You can assign `builder2` the result of the chain:

```
builder2 = builder2.AddLineColor("color").AddLineDash("dash");
```

Or just change `MyStyleBuilder` to a `class`, which will give it reference semantics.

```
public class MyStyleBuilder
```

See also [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13049/5133585)

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly because you are using a struct instead of a class. Structs are passed by value, so copies will be made, like when you are returning "this". Mutable structs are discouraged because it is so easy to make mistakes, see [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

So either change to a class, or to a readonly struct:

```
public readonly struct MyStyleBuilder
{
    private readonly string stringBuffer ;
    private MyStyleBuilder(string str) => stringBuffer = str;
   ...
   public MyStyleBuilder AddStyle(string prop, string value)
   {
        var style = $"{prop}:{value};";
        return new MyStyleBuilder(stringBuffer  + style);
    }
}
```

Note that a class and a readonly struct will behave differently. The later will produce modified copies, and that may make some use cases a bit easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

To add to already given answers, here's full code snippet presenting what is wrong:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ChainedStructBad();
        ChainedStructGood();
        ChainedRefType();
    }
    
    public static void ChainedRefType()
    {
        var @ref = new ChainedRefType();
        @ref
            .AddInfo("INFO 5")
            .AddInfo("INFO 6");
        Console.WriteLine($"ChainedRefType: {@ref}");
    }
    
    public static void ChainedStructGood()
    {
        var @struct = new ChainedStruct();
        @struct = @struct
            .AddInfo("INFO 3")
            .AddInfo("INFO 4");
        Console.WriteLine($"Good struct method: {@struct}");
    }
    
    public static void ChainedStructBad()
    {
        var @struct = new ChainedStruct();
        @struct
            .AddInfo("INFO 1")
            .AddInfo("INFO 2");
        Console.WriteLine($"Bad struct method: {@struct}");
    }
}

public class ChainedRefType
{
    private string _gatheredInfo = string.Empty;
    
    public ChainedRefType AddInfo(string value) 
    {
        _gatheredInfo += $"#value:{value}";
        return this;
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _gatheredInfo;
    }
}

public struct ChainedStruct 
{
    private string _gatheredInfo = string.Empty;
    
    public ChainedStruct(){}
    
    public ChainedStruct AddInfo(string value) 
    {
        _gatheredInfo += $"#value:{value}";
        return this;
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _gatheredInfo;
    }
}
```

This produces below output, which shows exactly what's the problem (already mentioned in other answers):

> Bad struct method: #value:INFO 1

> Good struct method: #value:INFO 3#value:INFO 4

> ChainedRefType: #value:INFO 5#value:INFO 6